# Wait for multiple elements using xpath in Selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

Is it possible to wait for multiple elements present on the page using xpath locators?

For example if I wanted to wait for ONE of elements A or B using xpath I'd use:

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//div[A] | //div[B]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

How would the command for waiting for BOTH elements look like?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I know XPath, but I don't know Selenium IDE.

So, based on what I know about XPath only, I would suggest this XPath statement :

```
<td>//div[A or B]</td>
```

is that make sense?

Comment: updated. Try that, and if still not working try this : `//div[A | B]`. If both failed I have no further idea, will delete this answer later.